# How to get time difference Duration totals grouped by Name and when Value changes in certain way?

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I'm looking for the Sum of time value differences between rows where Value was *initially* 1 and is now 0, grouped by Name.

Example data for a single Name, but there are many different Names in the real data.

```
+--------+---------------+---------------------+--------+
| RowNum |     Name      |      Timestamp      | Value  |
+--------+---------------+---------------------+--------+
|      1 | D1_HS_308_ALM | 2020-02-10 11:55:00 | 0      |
|      2 | D1_HS_308_ALM | 2020-02-10 11:51:00 | 0      |
|      3 | D1_HS_308_ALM | 2020-02-10 11:49:00 | NULL   |
|      4 | D1_HS_308_ALM | 2020-02-10 11:46:00 | 1      |
|      5 | D1_HS_308_ALM | 2020-02-10 08:02:00 | 0      |
|      6 | D1_HS_308_ALM | 2020-02-10 08:02:00 | NULL   |
|      7 | D1_HS_308_ALM | 2020-02-10 08:02:00 | 0      |
|      8 | D1_HS_308_ALM | 2020-02-10 07:56:00 | 1      |
|      9 | D1_HS_308_ALM | 2020-02-10 07:51:00 | 1      |
|     10 | D1_HS_308_ALM | 2020-02-10 07:50:00 | 0      |
+--------+---------------+---------------------+--------+
```

This data should return 11 minutes for Row 9-->7 transition and 5 minutes for Row 4-->2 transition; totaling 16 minutes for this Name.

I'm not sure how to accomplish this when it's not guaranteed that the next row has the correct Value change - sometimes it will be several or many rows later.

Comment: Nice job with sample data. I don't really understand the desired output. Are you saying only two rows in the output should have a value? Or should there only be 2 rows returned? And what is the datatype of the Value column? Is that a bit? And I assume this needs to partition on Name?

Comment: Desired output would be "D1_HS_308_ALM, 16" for that Name and Sum(Duration while 1).

It would be number of rows equal to the number of distinct Names.

Datatype of Value is INT, but is only ever 0/1/NULL.

Yes, partition by Name.

Comment: So only a single row would be returned from your sample data?

Comment: You really should post the desired output and an explanation of the business rules to calculate it. The more I look this question is more confusing it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE
(
    RowNum INT,
    Name VARCHAR(20),
    [Timestamp] DATETIME,
    Value INT
);

INSERT INTO @myTable
(
    RowNum,
    Name,
    [Timestamp],
    Value
)
VALUES
(1, 'D1_HS_308_ALM', '2020-02-10 11:55:00', 0),
(2, 'D1_HS_308_ALM', '2020-02-10 11:51:00', 0),
(3, 'D1_HS_308_ALM', '2020-02-10 11:49:00', NULL),
(4, 'D1_HS_308_ALM', '2020-02-10 11:46:00', 1),
(5, 'D1_HS_308_ALM', '2020-02-10 08:02:00', 0),
(6, 'D1_HS_308_ALM', '2020-02-10 08:02:00', NULL),
(7, 'D1_HS_308_ALM', '2020-02-10 08:02:00', 0),
(8, 'D1_HS_308_ALM', '2020-02-10 07:56:00', 1),
(9, 'D1_HS_308_ALM', '2020-02-10 07:51:00', 1),
(10, 'D1_HS_308_ALM', '2020-02-10 07:50:00', 0);

SELECT *,
       DATEDIFF(MINUTE, tStart, tEnd) AS duration
FROM
(
    SELECT t1.Name,
           MIN(t1.RowNum) AS rStart,
           MIN(t1.Timestamp) AS tStart,
           t.rNo AS rEnd,
           t.tEnd
    FROM @myTable t1
        OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP (1)
               t2.RowNum,
               t2.Timestamp
        FROM @myTable t2
        WHERE t1.Name = t2.Name
              AND t2.Timestamp > t1.Timestamp
              AND t2.Value = 0
        ORDER BY t2.Timestamp
    ) t(rNo, tEnd)
    WHERE t1.Value = 1
    GROUP BY t1.Name,
             t.rNo,
             t.tEnd
) tmp;
```

Update:

```
SELECT Name,
       Sum(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, tStart, tEnd)) AS duration
FROM
(
    SELECT t1.Name,
           MIN(t1.Timestamp) AS tStart,
           t.tEnd
    FROM @myTable t1
        OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP (1)
               t2.Timestamp
        FROM @myTable t2
        WHERE t1.Name = t2.Name
              AND t2.Timestamp > t1.Timestamp
              AND t2.Value = 0
        ORDER BY t2.Timestamp
    ) t(tEnd)
    WHERE t1.Value = 1
    GROUP BY t1.Name,
             t.tEnd
) tmp
group by name;
```

Comment: This gets me most of the way there... Can I request updates: The real data does not have RowNum column (I know that can be added somehow though), and can I get the output to only have 1 row {Name, Sum(Duration)} per Name?

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

- `min()` conditionally to get the next timestamp at value `0`.
- `lag()` to see the previous value.

Then filter down to the transition from 0 to 1 and do some date arithmetic:

```
select t.*,
       datediff(seconds, timestamp, next_ts_0) as duration
from (select t.*,
             min(case when value = 0 then timestamp end) over (partition by name order by timestamp desc) as next_ts_0,
             lag(value) over (partition by name order by timestamp) as prev_value
      from t.*
     ) t
where (prev_value = 0 or prev_value is null) and value = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modified the select query by Cetin as per your need:

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE
(
    RowNum INT,
    Name VARCHAR(20),
    [Timestamp] DATETIME,
    Value INT
);

INSERT INTO @myTable
(
    RowNum,
    Name,
    [Timestamp],
    Value
)
VALUES
(1, 'D1_HS_308_ALM', '2020-02-10 11:55:00', 0),
(2, 'D1_HS_308_ALM', '2020-02-10 11:51:00', 0),
(3, 'D1_HS_308_ALM', '2020-02-10 11:49:00', NULL),
(4, 'D1_HS_308_ALM', '2020-02-10 11:46:00', 1),
(5, 'D1_HS_308_ALM', '2020-02-10 08:02:00', 0),
(6, 'D1_HS_308_ALM', '2020-02-10 08:02:00', NULL),
(7, 'D1_HS_308_ALM', '2020-02-10 08:02:00', 0),
(8, 'D1_HS_308_ALM', '2020-02-10 07:56:00', 1),
(9, 'D1_HS_308_ALM', '2020-02-10 07:51:00', 1),
(10, 'D1_HS_308_ALM', '2020-02-10 07:50:00', 0);


SELECT tmp.Name,
       SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, tStart, tEnd)) AS duration
FROM
(
    SELECT t1.Name,
           --MIN(t1.RowNum) AS rStart,
           MIN(t1.Timestamp) AS tStart,
           --t.rNo AS rEnd,
           t.tEnd
    FROM @myTable t1
        OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP (1)
               --t2.RowNum,
               t2.Timestamp
        FROM @myTable t2
        WHERE t1.Name = t2.Name
              AND t2.Timestamp > t1.Timestamp
              AND t2.Value = 0
        ORDER BY t2.Timestamp
    --) t(rNo, tEnd)
    ) t(tEnd)
    WHERE t1.Value = 1
    GROUP BY t1.Name,
             --t.rNo,
             t.tEnd
) tmp
GROUP BY tmp.Name;
```